# Geforce rtx3070 Render doesn't work with CUDA

Tags: rendering

I recently updated my PC to AMD Ryzen 3700X + Geforce rtx3070 and today I tried to render something and blender 2.83, 2.8, 2.91 and also 2.79 tells me CUDA:

[image]

Also, earlier this morning with CUDA turned on my render preview window stopped working and now its showing me only lines and says render is paused:
[image]

Please advise what should be done to fix this.. I cannot work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First things first - have you updated your graphics drivers to the latest version?

Comment: Hello, if you mean in the NVIDIA app - then yes. Also, I have a PALIT version of graphic card and I downloaded the latest version there.

Comment: Hmmm. Only thing I can think to try is switching to 2.91 beta build  - it worked for a user in this post -https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/jjz3ny/getting_this_message_with_my_3080_fe_cuda_binary/gafy7hh/

Comment: Yeahh.. like I mentioned, I tried 2.91.. it was the first choice I downloaded. As far as I recall it worked at first, but then stopped.

Comment: A person in the post also mentioned 2.92 alpha as a possibility, I'm not sure it will work, but it's really the only suggestion I have left

Comment: This might just be an early adoption issue - the drivers and adapters just might not be there yet. I know around the time of the 2080 launch, users were getting a similar error, and this was to do with the missing file `kernel_sm_75.cubin` from the cycles lib folder. However, given the numbers, the correct file to fix your error should be `kernel_sm_86.cubin`, but I can find no evidence such a file exists anywhere (yet).

Comment: thank you my only saviour )) I will be waiting for some fix then))) will test out 2.92 a bit later too